# two select run in milliseconds but join make them slow

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

i have two select they run in milliseconds. but join of them ....! (over 10 second) deviceID is Non-clustered index in Transaction Table and Transaction table have millions data. sorry for my poor English. 
my query:

```
select * from 
(
select 
t.ChargeDeviceID,
count(*)  AS CountTrans, 
COALESCE(sum(cast(Amount as bigint)),0) as SumTrans 
from Transaction t
where t.RegionID in (select RegionID from region where ParentID = @RegionID and RegionTypeID <> 0)
and @StartDate <= TransactionDateTime 
and TransactionDateTime < DATEADD (day, 1 ,@EndDate)
group by t.ChargeDeviceID
) t1
join
(
select ChargeDeviceID, DeviceSerial,DeviceGroupID
from  ChargeDevice where RegionID in (select RegionID from region where ParentID = @RegionID and RegionTypeID <> 0)
)t2
on t1.ChargeDeviceID = t2.ChargeDeviceID
where t2.DeviceGroupID = (case when @DeviceGroupID = 0 then t2.DeviceGroupID else @DeviceGroupID end)
```

how can i make it run faster? thanks

Comment: Post both query plans. I guess not only have you joined them but added the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: i test join without Where and result was same.:(

Comment: Well anyway post the query plans if you can and we can start suggesting things (press CTRL-L)

Comment: Your query seems more complex than needed, and has a number of sub-selects, some of which are actually the same. I think rewriting as a single query instead of two queries and then subselect join them together will be better for you. Also - we do need to see plans to help

Comment: Why the derived tables.  You bury the indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find the answer!:) left join to Table have more data change and change where to join condition.

```
select * from 
(
select 
t.ChargeDeviceID,
count(*)  AS CountTrans, 
COALESCE(sum(cast(Amount as bigint)),0) as SumTrans 
from Transaction t
where t.RegionID in (select RegionID from region where ParentID = @RegionID and RegionTypeID <> 0)
and @StartDate <= TransactionDateTime 
and TransactionDateTime < DATEADD (day, 1 ,@EndDate)
group by t.ChargeDeviceID
) t1
left join
(
select ChargeDeviceID, DeviceSerial,DeviceGroupID
from  ChargeDevice where RegionID in (select RegionID from region where ParentID = @RegionID and RegionTypeID <> 0)
)t2
on t1.ChargeDeviceID = t2.ChargeDeviceID
and t2.DeviceGroupID = (case when @DeviceGroupID = 0 then t2.DeviceGroupID else @DeviceGroupID end)
```

Comment: Changing a join to left join means the query does something different.

Comment: But it returns same result.

Comment: 2 + 2 and 2 * 2 also returns the same result - while being different functionality.